# Let $f(x)=x^{4}-6x^{2}+5$. If $P(x_0,y_0)$ is a point such that $y_0>f(x_0)$ and there are exactly two distinct tangents through P

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

> Let $f(x)=x^{4}-6x^{2}+5$. If $P(x_0,y_0)$ is a point such that $y_0>f(x_0)$ and there are exactly two distinct tangents through P drawn to the curve $y=f(x)$, then find the maximum possible value of $y_0$.

The hint said P is the point of intersection of tangents drawn at inflection points.

I calculated inflection points, and they came out to be $(1,0), (-1,0)$.

I calculated tangents at these points and found the point of intersection to be $(0,8)$.

So, the answer is $8$, which is correct but the doubt is why this is happening this way. What's the importance of inflection point here?

Comment: I suppose there should be another condition that the tangents must be on opposite sides of the $y$-axis. In this case, $a = -1, b = 1$ should give the maximum $y_0$ as $8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the answer is correct.

For example the tangent to the curve at $x=-\frac32$ is
$$r: y=\frac{9}2x + \frac{53}{16}$$
and the tangent line to the curve at $x=-\frac14$ is
$$s : y=\frac{47}{16}x + \frac{1373}{256},$$
and they interesect at $P\left(\frac{21}{16},\frac{295}{32}\right)$.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

The correct answer is the following. The *supremum* of $y_0$ is the only real positive $y$-solution to the system
$$\begin{cases}y&=&x^4-6x^2+5\\ y&=&8x+8,\end{cases}$$
that is the ordinate of the interesction point between the given curve and the tangent line at the inflection point $(-1,0)$.

**We get $y_{sup}=32$** (see dashed line in the figure below).

[image]

In order to draw the above conclusion you can use the following observations.

1. Any point $P$ whose ordinate is such that $y> 8|x|+8$ (that is any point above the the two tangent lines shown in the figure) can be connected to the *concave* part of the graph $f(x)=x^4-6x^2+5$ only with a straight line whose angular coefficient has absolute value greater than $8$, which shows that such line cannot be tangent to the curve.
2. On the other hand, consider any point $P_1$ on the curve, whose abscissa $x_{P_1}$ is, e.g., $-1<x_{P_1}<0$, and let $r_1$ be the line tangent to the curve at $P_1$. By appropriately selecting a second tangency point $P_2$ with abscissa $-3<x_{P_2}<-1$ we can find a second tangent line $r_2$ whose intersection with $r_1$ is any point $P\in r_1$ with $x_P>x_{P_1}$.

Comment: So can the problem be solved?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta I have to put some more thought on that. As soon as I can :)

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Intuitively, $\sup\{y_0\} = \overline y$, where $\overline y$ is the ordinate of the interesection point between the curve and the tangent line in $(-1,0)$. But at the moment do not know how to rigorously prove the assertion.